# Configure second network card/interface

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

i'm configuring one server (ubuntu 12.04 64bits, with kvm) with 2 card adapters. The first one (eth0) is configured to work with virtual bridge (vbr0) for the DMZ interface. Ho can i condigure the second one (eth1) to work with the LAN interface (192.168.1.8 as static IP address).
Here is the actual configuration (/etc/newtork/interfaces )

```
auto lo eth0 eth1 br0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.4.8
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.4.255
network 192.168.4.0
gateway 192.168.4.1
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_fd 9
bridge_hello 2
bridge_maxage 12
bridge_stp off
```

Thanks for the support!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to /etc/newtork/interfaces:

```
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.8
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try tomorrow and post the result!